# Running pyiron under Windows leads to error about .pyiron configuration

Tags: pyiron

I installed pyiron according to the instructions under Windows via conda. Everything worked without any errors. Then, I started a new notebook, and ran the commands:

```
from pyiron import Project
```

where I got the message:

```
Fall back to default configuration: {'resource_paths': ['~/pyiron/resources'], 'project_paths': ['~/pyiron/projects']}
```

and then, I tried to start a new project via:

```
pr = Project('test')
```

Here, errors occurred such as:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f4cd01081291> in <module>
----> 1 pr = Project('test')

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyiron\project.py in __init__(self, path, user, sql_query)
    108 
    109     def __init__(self, path="", user=None, sql_query=None):
--> 110         super(Project, self).__init__(path=path, user=user, sql_query=sql_query)
    111         self.job_type = JobTypeChoice()
    112         self.object_type = ObjectTypeChoice()
```

and finally, the message:

```
ValueError: the current path C:/Users/nau/pyiron/test/ is not included in the .pyiron configuration. ['C:/Users/nau/pyiron/projects/']
```

(nau is my user name). Do I have to initialize a file .pyiron in a certain folder first? If yes, how? The folder C:/Users/nau/pyiron/projects/ didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug and should be fixed in the code - I am going to create a separate issue on Github shortly.

In the mean time you can fix it on your system, by either creating the folder manually:

```
C:/Users/nau/pyiron/projects/
```

And then execute the jupyter notebook in this folder.

Or you can create the pyiron configuration files by executing the following commands:

```
import pyiron
pyiron.install()
```

This is going to ask you:

```
It appears that pyiron is not yet configured, do you want to create a default start configuration (recommended: yes). [yes/no]:
```

And then you can confirm with `yes` which is going to create a `C:/Users/nau/.pyiron` file with the configuration. This file you can then update manually. By changing the line:

```
PROJECT_PATHS = C:/Users/nau/pyiron/projects/
```

to:

```
PROJECT_PATHS = C:/Users/nau/pyiron/
```

I hope this solves your issue.

Ps: Can you tell me which version of pyiron you are using? You can identify the version using `conda list pyiron`.

Comment: Your proposed solution worked. Thank you! Concerning your question, I use the pyiron version 0.2.10.

Comment: The most recent version is 0.3.10, Can you try if updating resolves the issue?

Comment: When I installed pyiron, I just executed  "conda install -c conda-forge pyiron"   in the Anaconda Powershell under Windows. I could not choose a version, and the version 0.2.10 was installed. Following your comment, I tried  "conda update pyiron"  which lead to some updates of other packages, but pyiron was still 0.2.10 (which I checked with "conda list pyiron"). How can I get the latest version under Windows?

Comment: Can you try? `conda install -c conda-forge pyiron=0.3.10`